# How can I read bitmaps in the GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, javax.imageio

We presently use javax.imageio.* in our Java code to read bitmaps. All we need to do is read them into a BufferedImage and to get the basic metadata (resolution, DPI, file format).

Which then leads to the question, what should we use instead of java.awt.image.BufferedImage (it also is not supported in GAE)?

And if possible - convert to PNG (from other formats) and resize a bitmap.

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0):

GAE has its own ImageService, described [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/).